# How to use EC2 Instance Profile in Nodejs application to access AWS Services?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a Nodejs application which runs on an EC2.

The EC2 has an instance profile attached to it.

How can I use the instance profile inside my Nodejs code so that my Nodejs code can access AWS Services like S3 bucket etc without using AWS Access Keys?

I found this link that's close to this topic but could not see any sample code provided there:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-iam.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that the role is attached to your instance, there is no further configuration.

from the documentation:

"We designed IAM roles so that your applications can securely make API requests from your instances, without requiring you to manage the security credentials that the applications use. Instead of creating and distributing your AWS credentials, you can delegate permission to make API requests using IAM roles as follows"

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html